# Replacing file content without readers clients access interruption

Tags: c#, concurrency, filesystems, writer

There is a service which constantly writes new content to a file:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(FileName))     // overwrites the file
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

The file is constantly accessed by multiple readers (including a web app which renders its content from this file). I have no control over readers clients code. The file should always be accessible to the readers. What is more, they should see the whole content and not the content in the middle of writing to the file.

Any techniques like this:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(FileName + ".tmp"))
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

File.Delete(FileName);
File.Move(FileName + ".tmp", FileName);
```

can lead to lack of content on a Web page (with some probability). And the service sometimes throws `IOException` exception with the message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

The question is: **How can file content be constantly replaced without readers clients access interruption?**

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is impossible.

Comment: By synchronizing read access to the file with a global mutex?

Comment: @Tergiver: Unfortunately there is no control over readers clients code.

Comment: how is your reader code hosted IIS, service, desktop app, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you could adapt [this module](http://acbcr.codeplex.com/) (full disclosure I wrote it) to inject synchronization into read requests.  You would do this by subclassing InterceptingHandler and adding code like:

```
SychronizingHandler : InterceptingHandler
{
    // ...

    Semaphore mySemaphore;

    protected override bool PreFilter(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
        context.RewritePath("myFilePath");
        if( mySemaphore == null)
        {
            bool created;
            mySemaphore = new Semaphore(100, 0, "semphoreName", out created);
        }

        if( mySemaphore != null)
        {
            mySemaphore.WaitOne();
        }
        reutrn true;
    }

    // note this function isn't in the base class
    // you would need to add it  and call it right after the call to
    // innerHandler.ProcessRequest
    protected override void PostFilter(System.Web.HttpContext context) 
    {
        mySemaphore.Release();
        return;
    }

    protected virtual void OnError(HttpContext context, Exception except)
    {
        mySemaphore.Release();
        return base.OnError(context, except);
    }
```

The desktop app is a bit trickier since it depends on the implementation details of application.  Hopefully in that case you have some way to extend it and add synchronization.

As Fun points out in the comments you could also do a conditional rewrite in your prefilter so that you weren't trying to access the file being written, which is a very good idea.

Comment: This could work, if the desktop app is able to read directly from IIS. Alternatively you could have the handle serves file A while file B is being written and serve file B while file A is being written. This way, you will avoid locking for too long.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately I have no control over reader clients code.